# Variables in path name and getting path not found error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm pulling my hair out.  The mkdir works with year (integer), but doesn't work with month (string) added.

```
year = 2013
month = MonthName(1)

'I have also tried just putting "January" in there as well
```

This works:

```
Path1 = "\\TEST\" & year & "\"
```

But this doesn't:

```
Path1 = "\\TEST\" & year & "\" & month & "\"
```

Suggestions? Thanks!

Final Fix:

Split Path1 into:

```
Path1: "\\TEST\" & year & "\"

Path2:  "\\TEST\" & year & "\" & month & "\"
```

With the checks:

```
If Len(Dir(Path1, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir Path1
End If
If Len(Dir(Path2, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir Path2
End If
```

Comment: What is the value of month when you get to that line?

Comment: Silly question... did you already create `\\TEST\ & year & "\"`? If not, you'll get an error.

Comment: Doug, "January" is the returned value.

Comment: Dan - yes, and that works just fine.

Comment: Dan - let me rephrase that.  It does create it, but I have a check in there to not create it if it's already there.  However, I keep deleting it to test everything.

Comment: So for example: You have already created `\\TEST\2013\`  but when you try to add `\\TEST\2013\January\` prior to deleting `\\TEST\2013\` it fails?

Comment: Dan - ok, that was my next question.  Do I have to create the first one first, and then add another line to create the 2nd directory?   I was hoping to just do it all in one line, but if not I can live with two.

Comment: Yes! If you try to create a sub folder without the parent folder already existing you get the error you mentioned.

Comment: Ok, well there was 30 minutes of wasted time...lol thanks again Dan!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create `"\\TEST\" & year & "\" & month & "\"` via [MkDir](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264553.aspx) unless `"\\TEST\" & year & "\"` already exists.

So expanding on your posted code, you could do this:

```
Path1 = "\\TEST\" & year & "\"
If DIR$(Path1, vbDirectory) <> "" then mkdir Path1
Path1 = "\\TEST\" & year & "\" & month & "\"
If DIR$(Path1, vbDirectory) <> "" then mkdir Path1
```